# Returning PID from SSH2 Command

Tags: php, ssh, exec

I am running a command to start a game server via SSH;

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'java -Xmx256M -Xms32M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui');
```

What i am trying to do is to get the PID of that process that has just started. The server is remote, hence the SSH2.

I need the PID so that i can assign it to the stop button and so when that is clicked, the PID will be killed.

I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen on an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4087436/1190388):

> Unfortunately, this extension is unmaintained since 2008 and is still in Beta state (0.11.0). You may want to look at some SSH2 3rd party libraries (some of them are LGPL or GPL).

Comment: What about this? It seems more up2date - http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html